# Is change in state visible to a party not involved in the transaction in case the party has access to that state from previous transactions?

Tags: blockchain, corda

Let's say Party-A initiates a transaction sharing state:State-1 with parties Party-B and Party-C. If Party A initiates another transaction only with Party B and modifies that state:State-1 then is that change in state visible to other party - Party C?

Answer (score 2):

When Party A modifies the state with Party B

**If**

- Party C is no longer a participant / extraReceipient of the transaction.
- The contract doesn't require the previous participant (Party C) to sign for the new outputs of  the transaction.

**Then** Party C

- Will only record the transaction that removed C as a participant to mark the state as **consumed**.
- Will record the consumed states but not the unconsumed states [See here on consumed/produced states](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/node/services/VaultService.kt)
- Will not record new unconsumed state if any more changes are made thereafter.

Comment: Could you please check the answer given by @Sagaranand? The answer is contradictory to yours. Could you cite any reference material?

Comment: He is not wrong, but also edited my answer to elaborate further.

Comment: Thanks but one more query related to 2nd condition in your if statement: Is it possible that the contract requires the previous participant (Party C) to sign for the new outputs of the transaction even though Party C is no longer a participant of the new output: updated State1?

Comment: Yes. The contract can enforce the signers = inputs.participants union outputs.participants.

Comment: Thanks but if, as per the 2nd condition in your IF statement, the contract requires previous participant (Party C) to sign for new outputs, then will the part in "Then" statement  hold? Will Party C be able to see changes in state:State1 even though he is not a participant anymore.

Comment: The `Then` still holds. If you keep requiring Party C to keep signing new changes to the state, C will store the transaction but not the state, but of course C can actually investigate his transaction storage to see the transaction trail. You could have 1 tx to remove Party C as participant then another 1 tx to make changes between A and B, so C only see as far as being removed as a participant.

Answer (score 2):

The State object is linked with list of Participant nodes. Whenever the state transition happens, it gets updated to all the nodes, defined in this participant list.

1. For the first transaction, the state gets saved to all the three nodes - Party A, B & C.
2. For the second transaction, the state change will be updated to all the three nodes - Party A, B & C.

The signatories of the transaction can be different than the nodes where the state is being saved or modified.

Comment: Could you please cite any reference material for your answer since the answer given by @Adrian is contradictory to yours?

Comment: From the below links you can understand the structure of State and Transaction. State have participants. Transaction have signing parties. https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-states.html             https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-transactions.html        

From below link, you can see the log status of cordapp execution. Last step is "Broadcasting transaction to participants". So transaction is sent for commit to participants (not signing parties).          https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html?highlight=participant

Comment: Thanks for the reference.